# ¿cómo asignar múltiples checkbox en un AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente código de un AlertDialog

```
CheckBox chkLunes,chkMartes,chkMier,chkJue,chkVie,chkSab;
            chkLunes=new CheckBox(getActivity());
            chkMartes=new CheckBox(getActivity());
            chkMier=new CheckBox(getActivity());
            chkJue=new CheckBox(getActivity());
            chkVie=new CheckBox(getActivity());
            chkSab=new CheckBox(getActivity());
            chkLunes.setChecked(false);
            chkMartes.setChecked(false);
            chkMier.setChecked(false);
            chkJue.setChecked(false);
            chkVie.setChecked(false);
            chkSab.setChecked(false);
            chkLunes.setText(getString(R.string.Lunes));
            chkMartes.setText(getString(R.string.Martes));
            chkMier.setText(getString(R.string.Miercoles));
            chkJue.setText(getString(R.string.Jueves));
            chkVie.setText(getString(R.string.Viernes));
            chkSab.setText(getString(R.string.Sabado));
    AlertDialog builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.AsignarAsistenciasTituloDialog))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.AsignarAsistenciasMensaje))
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                        .setView(chkLunes)
                        .setView(chkMartes)
                        .setView(chkMier)
                        .setView(chkJue)
                        .setView(chkVie)
                        .setView(chkSab)
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Aceptar), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.Cancelar), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        }).show();
```

la intención, es que se mostraran los 6 `checkBox` en el `Alertdialog`, pero, tal como está ahora, reemplaza el `chkLunes` hasta llegar a `chkSabado`.

**¿cómo puedo hacer que se muestren los 6 CheckBox en mi AlertDialog?**

Les dejo una referencia de cómo se ve mi `AlertDialog` Actualmente para ejemplificar:

[image: Ejemplo Alerdialog erróneo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear un Dialogo con multiples opciones usa [**setMultiChoiceItems**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMultiChoiceItems(int,%20boolean[],%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener)) :

```
builderDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList, is_checked,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        }
                    });
```

Puedes crear un listado de elementos el cual recibe como parametro y contienen las opciones deseadas, Ejemplo:

```
            List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

            list.add("Lunes");
            list.add("Martes");
            list.add("Miercoles");
            list.add("Jueves");
            list.add("Viernes");
            list.add("Sábado");
            list.add("Domingo");


            final CharSequence[] dialogList =  list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            //Puede crear una vista que contenga el titulo y la descripción.
            /*LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View viewTitle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_bar, null);
            builderDialog.setCustomTitle(viewTitle);*/

            builderDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            int count = dialogList.length;
            boolean[] is_checked = new boolean[count];

            builderDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList, is_checked,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                        }
                    });

            builderDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

            builderDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builderDialog.create();
            alert.show();
```

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Un placer, saludos!