# ¿Como seleccionar datos mostrados en un AlertDialog Android?

Tags: mysql, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me muestra los nombres que tengo insertados en una base de datos, pero necesito poder seleccionar el nombre y mostrar un toast que me diga cual seleccione.

```
public void clientes (View view){
    final SQLiteDatabase db = miConexion.getReadableDatabase();
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor miCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes", null);
            if (miCursor.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer nombresClientes = new StringBuffer();
            while (miCursor.moveToNext()) {
                nombresClientes.append(miCursor.getString(0) + "\n");
            }
            showMessage("Clientes", nombresClientes.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void showMessage(String title, String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
```

**Así me sale el AlertDialog**

[image: Así me sale el AlertDialog]

Comment: seleccionar donde? en un spinner, en un listview?  o en que?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91393/c%C3%B3mo-asignar-m%C3%BAltiples-checkbox-en-un-alertdialog esto te es útil?